# UIButton Tag overwrittened

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tags

How do you make sure that the UIButton tag is not overwritten by the previous tag?

for example:

```
(IBAction)addButton:(id)sender {

if (buttoncount == 2) return
buttoncount++

UIButton *newButton
...
// Should I change this to setTag?
newButton.tag = buttoncount;
   // This line doesn't seem to work
newbutton.tag = newButtonCount NSInteger(buttoncount);
...

[self.view addSubview:newButton];

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this code to do? tag is a property of UIView used to find it or identify it again in the future. You can ask a view to find -viewWithTag: that returns its subview with the specified tag.

Comment: Sorry you are right. I asked the question in the wrong way. This is related to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421940/one-uibutton-at-a-time" I was actually attempting to replace newButton.tag with newbutton.tag = newButtonCount NSInteger(buttoncount) to stop the newButton.tag of the previously generated button from being overwritten by the next generated button. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Objective-C:

```
newbutton.tag = newButtonCount NSInteger(buttoncount);
```

Remove that line, and your code should work as expected because buttonCount is incremented each time you add a button. The first button will be tagged 1, the second button will be tagged 2, and after that it seems that your code will prevent more than two buttons.